# unable to send href in anchor tag while sending a mail (GMAIL)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, email, gmail

**Explanation :** I am trying to send **href** in `html anchor tag` in email from MVC controller. It is working fine with `yohoo` mail and also with `outlook` but only getting issue with `Gmail`. Don't know why but when I am sending email to Gmail ID than `html anchor tag` just remove the href attribute from anchor tag. It is Happening only with gmail ID. I am using html template to send email.

**E-Mail Html Template**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">    
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>

<body leftmargin="0" marginwidth="0" topmargin="0" marginheight="0" offset="0">
    <center>
        <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="100%" width="100%" id="bodyTable">
            <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="top" id="bodyCell">
                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="templateContainer">
                        <tr>
                            <td style="text-align:center;vertical-align:top;">
                                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" id="templateHeader">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="headerContent" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:top;">
                                            <img src="cid:logo" style="max-width:600px;" id="headerImage" />
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="text-align:center;vertical-align:top;">
                                <table style="border:0;width:100%;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="templateBody">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td valign="top" class="bodyContent" mc:edit="body_content">
                                            <h1>Dear @ReceiverFirstNAME@,</h1>
                                            <p style="text-align:justify;">Please click on below URL to download your backup file for @CompanyName@</p>

                                            <p><a href="@BackupURL@" style="color:blue">Download</a></p>
                                            <p style="text-align:justify;">Download link will be expire after 24 Hours.</p>
                                            <br /> ********************************************************************************************
                                            <br /> This is a system generated mail, so please do not reply to this email id.
                                            <br /> ********************************************************************************************

                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="text-align:center;vertical-align:top;">
                                <table style="border:0;width:100%;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="templateFooter">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="footerContent" style="padding-top:0;vertical-align:top;text-align:center;">
                                            <em>Copyright © H2eFile 2015. All rights reserved.</em>
                                            <br />
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </center>
</body>    
</html>
```

**Generating E-Mail Body Code**

```
private AlternateView GenerateBodyTag(string companyName, string companyCode, string firstName, string lastName, string url, string logo) {
    StreamReader readtemplte = new StreamReader(Server.MapPath(@ "\\MailResource/ApplicationBackup.html"));
    string mailmsg = readtemplte.ReadToEnd();
    mailmsg = mailmsg.Replace("@ReceiverFirstNAME@", firstName + " " + lastName);
    mailmsg = mailmsg.Replace("@CompanyName@", companyName);
    mailmsg = mailmsg.Replace("@BackupURL@", url);

    byte[] data = System.Convert.FromBase64String(logo);
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(data);
    LinkedResource linkLogo = new LinkedResource(ms);
    linkLogo.ContentId = "logo";
    AlternateView objAv = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(mailmsg, null, MediaTypeNames.Text.Html);
    objAv.LinkedResources.Add(linkLogo);
    return objAv;
}
```

Only in Gmail don't know why href is removed automatically. I traced above code it seems fine but unable to traced it out why issue with gmail. So please make me correct where I am doing mistake. If more information required than please let me know I will update question.

Comment: It is possible that Gmail itself filters the message and removes undesired html tags due to user security. A suspicious url in the message might be deliberately removed by Google before the recepient receives it. Perhaps you need to check how to comply with Gmail content policies, unfortunately I cannot point you to any appropriate resources about that.

Comment: @IvayloSlavov Thank you for sharing your knowledge. But there might be any other way.

Comment: see my answer for detail, it includes my previous comment and a potential suggestion

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that Gmail itself filters the message and removes undesired html tags due to user security. A suspicious url in the message might be deliberately removed by Google before the recepient receives it. Perhaps you need to check how to comply with Gmail content policies, unfortunately I cannot point you to any appropriate resources about that.

The only workaround I can think of is reformatting the link tag. It should either contain text with the link itself (so the receiver sees what is the actual link) and be made to open in new window/tab (by using "target="_blank" ).

For example javascript events assigned to a link makes it suspicious, or might trigger the spam filter - in an email links should point to resources directly. A link name different from the target, or not suggesting what is going to happen if you follow it could also raise some alarms.

I suppose Google might be using part of, or their entire link ranking algorithm which is also employed by their search engine (PageRank). Someone familiar with SEO could help you further in making your links more appealing to google's search engine, and that could result in Gmail not to treat them the way you experience.

Comment: Not working i tried to replaced as follow '<p><a href="@BackupURL@" target="_blank" style="color:blue; cursor:pointer" data-url="@BackupURL@" onclick="Downloadbackup(this);">Download</a></p>' is't just convert like this '<a style="color:blue">Download</a>'

Comment: A good thing would be to add that url tag to your question, my bad I did not ask for that earlier. Avoid javascript calls on `onclick` events from an email message. Definitely, Goggle will have reasons to remove or block such links.

Comment: I checked after removing javascript and onclick also but still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add the `http://` in front of your link because Google removes the suspicious IP, port number and link tag. 
Your link should use a proper protocol.

Comment: That doesn't solve the problem. Google deletes even https:// links.

Comment: I found that google removes the link from emails if its considered "spam". This is why emails include the actual link at the bottom so you can copy it.